# php url rewrite moving page from old fold to new fold

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, header

I met some problem when moving page from old fold to new fold.

my old `.htacess` in `/var/www/html`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^items/products/(\d+)/(.*)?$ items/products.php?number=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I updrade my site. build a new folder `/var/www/html/2014`

Then another `sub .htacess` in `/var/www/html/2014

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /2014/
RewriteRule ^phone/products/(\d+)/(.*)?$ phone/products.php?number=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I want move `www.example.com/items/products/1234/iphone-5c` to `www.example.com/2014/phone/products/1234/iphone-5c`

I tried add the follow code in old page `items/products.php`

```
<?php
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header('http://www.example.com/2014/phone/products/'.$_GET['number'].'/'.$_GET['name']);
exit;
?>
```

error log:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

I modify `old .htacess` in  `/var/www/html`

```
RewriteRule ^item/products/(\d+)/(.*)?$ items/products.php?number=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
=>
RewriteRule ^2014/phone/products/(\d+)/(.*)?$ items/products.php?number=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

It redrict to `404 page`, how to do in right way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep this in `/var/www/html/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^items/products/(\d+)/(.*)?$ 2014/phone/products.php?number=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Keep this in `/var/www/html/2014/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /2014/
RewriteRule ^phone/products/(\d+)/(.*)?$ phone/products.php?number=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And **remove your PHP code for redirecting**. Test it in a new browser.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the same PHP file, it doesn't appear that you are distinguishing between the URL of the request, and instead sending *every* request to:

```
<?php
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header('http://www.example.com/2014/phone/products/'.$_GET['number'].'/'.$_GET['name']);
exit;
?>
```

Check your redirect logic to only send pages that are using the old URL via the code above.

Comment: i am using wp. I am sure i am using the same PHP. I have  `echo 'http://www.example.com/2014/phone/products/'.$_GET['number'].'/'.$_GET['name'];` in items/products.php with old code. than the page show `http://www.example.com/2014/phone/products/1234/iphone-5c` mouse right open in new browser tab, it show well. but change in header code, waring in htacess.